# How to just minify (and nothing else) a JS worklet file in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker, css-paint-api

The [JavaScript Worklet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet) interface only accepts [a file with an ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaintWorklet#Examples) as the argument to the `Worklet.addModule` method.  I have an outside-of-webpack workaround to minify my CSS Paint worklet file and place it in my dist folder, but it makes iterating in development slower.  I want to process this file through webpack with minification only, no transpilation, no webpack cruft wrapping the class in a function, those don't work.

I have searched all day and tried `noParse` and excluding from Babel but I am still getting the minified class wrapped in a function.  Is there a way to minify only through webpack?

```
//entry point

  //my workaround

    CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('./demo.min.js');// I minify and name it 

  //can I do the following?

    import(/* webpackChunkName: "paint-worklet" */ './demo')
    .then((demo) => CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(demo));

//output worklet

  //my workaround

    class Demo{......
    ...(minified)
    ...
    ......}registerPaint("demo",Demo);// defined and everything works

  //webpacked and excluded from Babel

    (window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[2],
    {w0gx:function(t,e){class r......
    ...
    ...
    .......registerPaint("demo",r)}}]);// wrapped in function and undefined
```

It is not necessary to import the worklet like you usually do with a webpack module, you just call `addModule` with it.  I need it minified and in `dist/` and then I need a way to get the hashed name at compile time to make it the argument to `addModule`.  A dynamic import seems like it would work so the worklet is a separate chunk, and after the promise resolves you call `addModule` with it, but since the worklet file is wrapped in a function, the browser throws an error saying that `registerPaint()`, which you call with the class, is not defined.